# How can I use Knowledge Based Authentication with Embedded Signing (Recipient View)?

Tags: docusignapi

I want to use knowledge based auth with as the authentication method specified in recipient view request. Right now, I have authentication_method set to 'None' because nowhere in the docusign documentation have they specified which parameter strings they accept for that. In docusign sandbox, were have a lot of templates where each role is manually defined as requiring KBA, but when I send the envelopes they are not being asked these questions. I think it is because in recipient view request I am specifying that auth_method is None, but again, I don't see a way out of this, not do I know any alternatives since it's not laid out in the documentation. I'm using the python SDK

```
374         authentication_method = 'None'
378         recipient_view_request = RecipientViewRequest(
379             authentication_method=authentication_method,
380             client_user_id='1',
381             return_url=return_url,
382             user_name='name'
383             email='email'
384         )
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!! Please upvote all answers that are helpful including answers to others' questions. PLEASE accept/check the best answer to your own questions. Thank you.

Comment: I now see that you accepted the answer, thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great Question. Thanks Davis. You do that in the Recipient object not the ViewRequest. We're in the process of getting the Python code samples updated to add this example. Here is the C# code we have for now:

```
Signer signer1 = new Signer()
{
    Name = signerName,
    Email = signerEmail,
    ClientUserId = "1",   // Optional: sets the signer as embedded
    RoutingOrder = "1",
    Status = "Created",
    DeliveryMethod = "Email",
    RecipientId = "1", //represents your {RECIPIENT_ID}
    Tabs = signer1Tabs,
    RequireIdLookup = "true", //will use recipient auth
    IdCheckConfigurationName = "ID Check" //indicates KBA Auth
};
```

Note that "ID Check" is KBA and not IDV.
Also note, that you do need "Email" as that's how the recipient gets the notice about the envelope.
This example assumes you defined your tabs elsewhere in the signer1Tabs object.

I think it should be simple to get this to work in Python. Let me know if you still can't get it.

One last note - your account should have KBA enabled. If you created your sandbox recently in DocuSign - it should, but if you have an old one - it may not.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using TemplateRoles in my envelope definition, and do not see a way to add IdCheckConfigurationName in this object.

Comment: look here Davis - https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Templates/TemplateRecipients
when you create the template using the API, the recipient object does include this property. You cannot add it to a template when you create an envelope from it. So if that's what you were trying to do - can't do it. the KBA auth is part of the template and cannot be done on an envelope by envelope basis if created from template

Comment: Ok so I am using premade templates specified in my docusign sandbox account. These templates have all the template roles defined with KBA auth for each one. The problem is that I do not get the KBA auth steps when I open the contract, it just takes me right to the signing ceremony. I'm wondering if this is an issue with my settings in sandbox, or if these KBA steps are not enabled in sandbox? I'm also wondering if setting auth_method='None' is having an effect on this?

Comment: Nevermind, there was some internal miscommunication, the auth is working as long as it's defined in the sandbox account.